# SNAP package FFMPEG can't access any file (access denied). How can i fix that?

Tags: permissions, 19.04, snap, ffmpeg

I've installed FFMPEG SNAP package (from Snapcrafters).

But it **can't see/access any file in my home directory**.

It always returns **"filexyz.mp4: Permission denied" error** . Doesn't not matter when I use **sudo** prefix or not.

FFMPEG installed from ubuntu repositories using **sudo apt install ffmpeg** worked. So this si snap package specific problem.

[image: terminal screenshot here]

Comment: right now, I have only workaround solution for this problem. When SNAP package is installed using --devmode attribute. Then it works and there is no "can't see any file" problem at all. So we have temporary solution here: **sudo snap install ffmpeg --devmode**

Comment: another workaround sollution is using IN/OUT pipes. **cat input.mp4 | ffmpeg -i pipe:0 -f matroska pipe:1 | cat > output.mkv** but it creates broken output files to me (its impossible to seek output files in media player and sometimes first keyframe is broken). Those outputs have to be fixed using mkvtoolnix ...

Comment: Can you try using absolute path and add escaping wherever necessary?

Comment: Using absolute paths has no effect. Still returns "Permission denied" error

Comment: Can't duplicate, works fine here both with the stable and edge versions. Though am using 19.10 not 19.04. Did you install thru Ubuntu software or cli?

Comment: I've used cli (sudo snap install ffmpeg). Maybe it is fixed in 19.10 ... that's good to know.

Answer (score 7):

There is no need to use --devmode or in/out pipes.

1. Just open your graphical Software Center and find your FFMPEG app installed from SNAP repository.
2. There you can find PERMISSIONS button, click on it, and enable "Read/write files on removable storage devices" permission. Then it works and you can read/write files in your own home directory.

[More info about snap apps permissions here](http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/snap-application-permissions)

This is bug, imo. Home directory is not "removable device" :-) But it works ...

Comment: add ffmpeg:removable-media permission 
 - https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/580420/15200