# Software not allowed to access folders

Tags: permissions, software-recommendation, ffmpeg

I'm trying to tell audacity where my ffmpeg is seeing as it doesn't seem to want to do it iself but when I go to access the folder, /usr, it says permission denied. The same was true for something I was trying to do with fre:ac, any recommendations?

Comment: Had the same problem, tried to deinstall using the general ubuntu package manager.
Select Audacity and there was not just the uninstall but also a permissions button.
Tried that one and found a deselected switch named
"Read/write files on removable storage devices"
select - retry - and it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you installed Audacity from the Ubuntu Software program, this sounds like an issue with Snap applications. Snaps are isolated from the rest of your system except for a few specially permitted functions, which is great for single standalone apps but causes an awful lot of problems with others.

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1176078/snap-package-ffmpeg-cant-access-any-file-access-denied-how-can-i-fix-that) might be of some help, but it is likely that just uninstalling the snap and installing the package from the Ubuntu repos will work better than trying to get snaps to behave.

To do this, uninstall Audacity from Ubuntu software and run `sudo apt install audacity` in a terminal.

Comment: Would you say that it'd be a good rule to work by that if an app is entirely self sufficient it is fine to use the snap version, but if it interfaces with other stuff beyond it's own installation files, I should install via terminal?

Comment: It's a question of opinion really. I tend to try using a snap in the first instance then switch to apt if I encounter any issues with it.