# Foliate book reader, snap package, can't open ebooks from NTFS partitions

Tags: permissions, mount, snap, drive, foliate

I have just installed the [Foliate](https://github.com/johnfactotum/foliate) via snap `sudo snap install foliate` on Ubuntu 20.04.

I can successfully open epub book that are in my home folder, but when I try opening books that are in mounted NTFS partitions, it returns an error. See screenshot below:

[image]

The file permissions are:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 subroot subroot   875977 Dec 17 22:50 Chosen_but_Free__A_Balanced_View_5976470859.epub*
```

This then logs these details in the syslog:

```
May  5 10:48:52 subroot kernel: [ 7738.695746] audit: type=1400 audit(1588664932.924:3252): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.foliate.foliate" name="/proc/21158/mounts" pid=21158 comm="com.github.john" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
May  5 10:48:52 subroot com.github.john[21158]: JS WARNING: [resource:///com/github/johnfactotum/Foliate/js/window.js 1119]: reference to undefined property "_loading"
May  5 10:48:53 subroot com.github.john[21158]: JS WARNING: [resource:///com/github/johnfactotum/Foliate/js/tts.js 33]: reference to undefined property "_epub"
May  5 10:48:53 subroot kernel: [ 7738.855762] audit: type=1107 audit(1588664933.084:3253): pid=824 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.11" pid=21256 label="snap.foliate.foliate" peer_pid=825 peer_label="unconfined"
May  5 10:48:53 subroot kernel: [ 7738.855762]  exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
May  5 10:48:53 subroot kernel: [ 7739.078823] audit: type=1107 audit(1588664933.308:3254): pid=824 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/DisplayDevice" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.48" pid=21256 label="snap.foliate.foliate" peer_pid=1277 peer_label="unconfined"
May  5 10:48:53 subroot kernel: [ 7739.078823]  exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
May  5 10:48:53 subroot kernel: [ 7739.241415] audit: type=1107 audit(1588664933.468:3255): pid=824 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/DisplayDevice" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.48" pid=21255 label="snap.foliate.foliate" peer_pid=1277 peer_label="unconfined"
May  5 10:48:53 subroot kernel: [ 7739.241415]  exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
May  5 10:48:53 subroot kernel: [ 7739.359433] audit: type=1400 audit(1588664933.588:3256): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.foliate.foliate" name=2F6D656469612F737562726F6F742F46696C65732F43687269737469616E2065626F6F6B732F43686F73656E5F6275745F467265655F5F415F42616C616E6365645F566965775F353937363437303835392E65707562 pid=21256 comm="pool" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
```

Comment: Does https://askubuntu.com/a/1176083/248158 help?

Comment: @DKBose I have no "Read/write files on removable storage devices" permission, I just have "Access files in your home folder" which is on.

Comment: Okay! Some snaps such as that of `okular` do: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKSOU.png

Comment: Seems to be a bug, since the snap app is missing the "Read/write files on removable storage devices" permission. I have opened an issue on github on the same: https://github.com/johnfactotum/foliate/issues/332#issue-612478797

Comment: BTW, I came across `sudo snap connect ksnip:removable-media` in https://github.com/ksnip/ksnip/pull/313 which is my fave screen annotation tool. Could you try something similar?